# MySQL insert query not responding

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I try to insert data into MySQL with PHP code or phpMyAdmin, but the server hangs for a long time before finally printing:

```
The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

I can add values to the database with logging in MySQL using a SSH connection. I am using PHP Version 5.1.6 with MySQL Client API version 5.0.77.

I see an error in the log:

```
Version: '5.0.77' socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306 Source distribution
```

Comment: Please post the code that you're using, that isn't working, to insert the data. That way we have a basis for offering help.

Comment: code is not important i fill the table from phpmyadmin it doesn't do but i paste it to the ssh it insert. There is global post problem

Comment: You're on a website that solves *coding* problems/issues, you're *unable* to use your code to achieve something you can do when logging into the MySQL server and you don't think code is important? ...should we just try and *guess* what's going on?

Comment: Hang on, *how* are you trying to insert data? Via a script or through your web admin panel? If it's via a script we can help, if it's via your web-admin panel then you need to talk to your web-host and ask them for help.

Comment: i want to say that if i dont use code so if i use phpmyadmin to try basic insert to a table it doesnt response ??

Comment: If this isn't coding related, you might get more traction on this sort of issue over on serverfault.com

Comment: That isn't an error. Have you changed the log warning level?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the MySQL error logs?

If you set the log warnings level above 1 aborted connections are written to the error log (as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)

As such, this is probably a good first port of call.

Comment: Version: '5.0.77'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution

this error i see in the log

Comment: Er... what error would that be? (NB: Update you question with the error.)